# Perl how to modify parameter

Tags: perl, parameter-passing, subroutine

How can the SOCKET recv function modify the value of the scalar $PDU directly?
Usually this syntax is a pass by value not a pass by reference, I assumed up to now at least.

```
my $PDU; 
my $addr = $socket->recv($PDU, MAXBYTES);
```

I want to use this effect for my own purpose so 
best would be a handy test subroutine which depicts how this can be achieved.

Like:

```
my $PDU="orig";
sub test {
  my $par1=shift;
  $par1="test";
}
print "$PDU\n";
```

As you know this will result into "orig" not "test".

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Hermann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be well documented when having such behavior,

```
my $PDU="orig";
sub test {
  $_[0] = "test";
}

test($PDU);
print "$PDU\n";
```

or

```
sub test {
  my ($par1) = map \$_, @_;

  $$par1 = "test";
}
```

output

```
test
```